# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-settings

I am using Django to create a web app, and when I tried to use the `py manage.py runserver` command, I got this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'`

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'

(.venv) C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp>py manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'

(.venv) C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp>py manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 387, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 9, in check_database_backends
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 216, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\Django\travelApp\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\n_mac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp'
```

I have no idea what is happening, as `travelApp` is not a module, it is my project name, so I don't know why it is treating it like one.

By the way, here is my `settings.py` file if that helps.

```
"""
Django settings for travelApp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i1kf*^g1+dt*8n9bgcl80$d!970186x(x(9z2)7dfy1ynlxixn'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

EMAIL_HOST_USER = "koolfacts67@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "m80222jms"

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sights.apps.SightsConfig',
    'itineraries.apps.ItinerariesConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'travelApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  '/home/django/myproject/templates',
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'travelApp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'railway',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'dRfHDaVZymxUWsZzCRtq',
        'HOST': 'containers-us-west-182.railway.app',
        'PORT': '6045',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'US/Central'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")]
```

Anybody know what is happening?

Comment: "when I tried to use the `py manage.py runserver` command" - when you do this, what is the current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

On the error from terminal I can see ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"travelApp' has extra double quotes fix this in your code and it will start working. Its a syntax error which is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, but I still don't know why my project thinks `travelApp` is a module when it is my project.